# Shared vector Synchronization with an atomic boolean

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, thread-safety, mutex

I am having a shared vector which gets accessed by two threads.

A function from thread A pushs into the vector and a function from thread B swaps the vector completely for processing.

```
    MovetoVec(PInfo* pInfo)
    {
       while(1)
        {
            if(GetSwitch())
            {
                swapBucket->push_back(pInfo);
                toggles = true;
                break;
            }
            else if(pInfo->tryMove == 5)
            {
                delete pInfo;
                break;
            }
            pInfo->tryMove++;
            Sleep(25);
        }
    }
```

The thread A tries to get atomic boolean `toggles` to true and pushes into vector.(*the above `MoveToVec` function will be called by many number of threads*). The function GetSwitch is defined as

```
GetSwitch()
{
   if(toggles)
   {
      toggles = false;
      return TRUE;
   }
   else
        return FALSE;
}
```

`toggles` here is atomic_bool.And the another function from thread B that swaps the vector is

```
    GetClassObj(vector<ProfiledInfo*>* toSwaps)
    {
        if(GetSwitch())
        {
            toSwaps->swap(*swapBucket);
            toggles = true;
        }
    }
```

If GetSwitch returns false then the threadB does nothing. Here i dint use any locking. It works in most of the cases. But some time one of the `pInfo` objects in swapBucket is NULL. I got to know it is because of poor synchronization.

I followed this type of GetSwitch() logic just to neglect the overhead caused by locking. Should i drop this out and go back to mutex or critical section stuffs?

Answer (score 7):

Your `GetSwitch` implementation is wrong. It is possible for multiple threads to acquire the switch simultaneously.

An example of such a scenario with just two threads:

```
 Thread 1                 | Thread 2
--------------------------|--------------------------
 if (toggles)             |
                          | if (toggles)
     toggles = false;     |
                          |     toggles = false;
```

The if-test and assignment are not an atomic operation and therefore cannot be used to synchronize threads on their own.

---

If you want to use an atomic boolean as a means of synchronization, you need to compare and exchange the value in one atomic operation. Luckily, C++ provides such an operation called [`std::compare_exchange`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/compare_exchange), which is available in a weak and strong flavor (the weak one may spuriously fail but is cheaper when called in a loop).

Using this operation, your `GetSwitch` method would become:

```
bool GetSwitch()
{
    bool expected = true; // The value we expect 'toggles' to have
    bool desired = false; // The value we want 'toggles' to get

    // Check if 'toggles' is as expected, and if it is, update it to the desired value
    bool result = toggles.compare_exchange_strong(&expected, desired);

    // The result of the compare_exchange is true if the value was updated and false if it was not
    return result;
}
```

This will ensure that comparing and updating the value happens atomically.

Note that the C++ standard does not guarantee an atomic boolean to be lock-free. In your case, you could also use [`std::atomic_flag`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag) which is guaranteed to be lock-free by the standard! Carefully read the example though, it works a tad bit different than atomic variables.

---

Writing lock-free code, as you are attempting to do, is quite complex and error-prone.

My advice would be to write the code with locks first and ensure it is 100% correct. Mutexes are actually surprisingly fast, so performance should be okay in most cases. A good read on lock performance: http://preshing.com/20111118/locks-arent-slow-lock-contention-is

Only once you have profiled your code, and convinced yourself that the locks are impacting performance, you should attempt to write the code lock-free. Then profile again because lock-free code is not necessarily faster.